# upload to S3 with BOM

Tags: encoding, amazon-s3, upload

I want to upload file to S3 with BOM. How can I do this?

```
var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);

string content = "hello";
byte[] b = DefaultEncoding.GetBytes(content);

using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream(b))

{        
   var request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest                                
   {                                    
      BucketName = bucket,                                    
      InputStream = fileStream,                                    
      Key = NormalizePath(Path.Combine(folder, file.Name)),                                
   };
}

transferUtility.Upload(request);
```

When I download file from S3 it's UTF-8, but not UTF-8-BOM

Comment: Please elaborate. Do you mean you have a text file that has a BOM, and you wish to upload it? Then upload it. Do you mean you have a text file without BOM and want to upload it as if it had one? Then add one and upload it. Also, did you just make up a content-encoding? What is that line supposed to do?

Comment: I changed code a little bit. I want to upload file that had a BOM.

Comment: So you want to add a BOM at runtime?

Comment: As I understand when I do this action "DefaultEncoding.GetBytes" I add BOM to my byte[] b or not? But yes, I have content "hello" and I want to upload file with this content and file have to have BOM

Comment: No, you can get the BOM bytes using `Encoding.GetPreamble()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);

string content = "hello";
byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble().Concat(DefaultEncoding.GetBytes(content)).ToArray();

using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream(b))

{        
   var request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest                                
   {                                    
      BucketName = bucket,                                    
      InputStream = fileStream,                                    
      Key = NormalizePath(Path.Combine(folder, file.Name)),                                
   };
}

transferUtility.Upload(request);
```